# Clear Timeout set in click event in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm wondering how to clear a timeout, which is set in an onclick event in React.
I'm aware you can easily cancel timeouts, when they are set in 'useEffect', but how about this use case?

```
export default function SomeComponent() {
    const onClick = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // dome some logic like API calls,
            // which should be terminated, in case the component
            // is unmounted
        }, 2_500)
    }

  return (
    <div><button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button></div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your question already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499969/settimeout-and-cleartimeout-in-react, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your timeout in a manner similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout#examples) example from MDM Web Docs is likely the solution you're after.
In this case, you can add a useEffect to clear on component unmount.

```js
/* Code taken from MDN Docs */
const alarm = {
  remind(aMessage) {
    alert(aMessage);
    this.timeoutID = undefined;
  },

  setup() {
    if (typeof this.timeoutID === 'number') {
      this.cancel();
    }

    this.timeoutID = setTimeout((msg) => {
      this.remind(msg);
    }, 1000, 'Wake up!');
  },

  cancel() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutID);
  }
};

/* Clear timeout on component unmount */
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    alarm.cancel()
  }
}, [alarm])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can save the timeout to a state and then clear it in the useEffect like this:

```js
export default function SomeComponent() {
    const [timeoutInstance, setTimeoutInstance] = useState(null);
    const onClick = () => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            // dome some logic like API calls,
            // which should be terminated, in case the component
            // is unmounted
        }, 2_500);
        setTimeoutInstance(timeout);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        if(timeoutInstance) {
          clearTimeout(timeoutInstance);
          setTimeoutInstance(null);
        }
      }
    }, []);

    return (
      <div><button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button></div>
    )
}
```